# Get TokenSecret from AuthorizedTokenResponse

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I'm using dotnetopenauth to check access with Google Account. After confirming access I get back AccessTokenResponse which is of type *DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Messages.AuthorizedTokenResponse*. It has a property *AccessToken* so I could grab the AccessToken, but how to get the *TokenSecret*? In the debugger I've seen that the TokenSecret is available but there is no property for it :-(
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, found it: It's in the InMemoryTokenManager using function 'GetTokenSecret'.

Comment: Correct.  The design leans toward you not having to fetch the secret explicitly in this way, however.  You're supposed to supply your own token manager which will persist the token and its secret when DotNetOpenAuth originally gives it to the token manager.